# After I submit a new Web Extension to Firefox AMO, is there an API to automate future updates?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm going through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Submitting_to_AMO) documentation for submitting a new WebExtension to AMO and I'm a little confused.  My end goal is that I want to be able to automate everything and I have it working all fine with Google Chrome Extensions but I'd also like to do it with FireFox extensions as well.

I understand that when I first create a new WebExtension for FF I need to submit it manually and I'm fine doing that.  I just want to be able to automate all future update versions, have AMO handle updating users, and have it listed on their [Add-On "store"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) (or whatever it's called)

Is this possible?

I have looked at the web-ext CLI and I see that it has build, signing, and publish capabilities but there's the caveat of it all being "self-signed" and that you have to handle updating users which, for now, I don't want to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their [REST API for signing](https://addons-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html)

```
curl "https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/@my-addon/versions/1.0/"
    -g -XPUT --form "upload=@build/my-addon.xpi"
    -H "Authorization: JWT <jwt-token>"
```

Or the node [`web-ext`](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext) package that you found will submit to the store via the `web-ext sign` command. [Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext/issues/804)

There's also [web-ext-submit](https://github.com/fregante/web-ext-submit) which makes it easy to submit it in Travis.

Comment: thanks!  I think since I want to call it from a script I'll use spawnSync and check the stdout for all, or part, of the response copy:  `Your add-on has been submitted for review. It passed validation but could not be automatically signed because this is a listed add-on`  At least that way I'll know it was successfully submitted.  Hopefully `web-ext` will take your suggestion to add a `submit` argument

Comment: For future folks trying to deploy extensions automagically, this looks promising: https://github.com/LinusU/wext-shipit